# Why click event is fired first time only?

Tags: jquery, dropdown, twitter-bootstrap, events

I have a Bootstrap 4 input group with a dropdown button. I need to change the href attribute value of links in dropdown depending on value inserted in the input text field. I'd to change the href(s) when user click on dropdown but the click event is fired first time only, what's wrong?

```
<div class="my-container">
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message here..." aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Invia a...<i class="fas fa-paper-plane mx-2"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Donald Duck</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mickey Mouse</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Daenery Targaryen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$( '.my-container' ).on( 'click', '[data-toggle="dropdown"]', function() {
    let message_val = $( '#message' ).val();

    $( '.dropdown-item' ).each( function() {
        let href = $( this ).attr( 'href' );

        href += '?text=' + encodeURI( message_val );
        $( this ).attr( 'href', href );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Do you realize after first click the like will be `?text=one` and second it will be `?text=one?text=two` and third time it would be `?text=one?text=two?text=three`

Answer (score 0):

try this. Modify you html in:

```
<div class="my-container" id="customContainer">----</div>
```

and in yout jquery:

```
$( '#customContainer' ).on( 'click', '[data-toggle="dropdown"]', function() {
    let message_val = $( '#message' ).val();

    $( '.dropdown-item' ).each( function() {
        let href = $( this ).attr( 'href' );

        href += '?text=' + encodeURI( message_val );
        $( this ).attr( 'href', href );
    } );
} );
```

If the first solution doesn't work  you cna try:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="dropdown"]', function(){
    //etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(document)` as your parent selector, this is good practice because it allows dynamic elements to receive the same function.

Also, rather than concatenating the href to your variable every time, create a new variable that will be '?text=' + message value, otherwise every time you click "change" the value will be appended to the old href variable.

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="dropdown"]', function() {
  let message_val = $('#message').val();

  $('.dropdown-item').each(function() {
    let href = $(this).attr('href');

    var newhref = '?text=' + encodeURI(message_val);
    $(this).attr('href', newhref);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message here..." aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">change<i class="fas fa-paper-plane mx-2"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">one</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">two</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">three</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tried both solutions, nothing changes, same results but I can't understand why...

Comment: Not sure what the problem could be, are you getting any errors? @icolumbro